# basic edit.php won´t update the data

Tags: php, edit

I have a small (42 hours) problem with my code trying to edit article
- just the basic editNews.php

When I choose article to edit the data appears in the forms from the DB and when
I hit "update" it returns no error but the data wasn´t updated

```
<?PHP 
connection to database blah blah 
?> 

<?php 


if(isset($_POST['update'])) 
{   
$newsid = $_POST['newsid']; 
$date=$_POST['date']; 
$time=$_POST['time']; 
$location=$_POST['location']; 

$result=mysql_query("UPDATE news SET date='$date',time='$time',location='$location', WHERE newsid=$newsid"); 

header("Location: listNews.php"); 
} 
} 
?> 


<?php 

$newsid = $_GET['newsid']; 

$result=mysql_query("select * from news where newsid=$newsid"); 

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$date = $res['date']; 
$time = $res['time']; 
$location = $res['location']; 


} 
?>
```

This is the form - just the normal one....

```
<form method="post" action="editNews.php" name="form1">
```

each item is like

```
<input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php echo $location;?>" id="UserName">
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="newsid" value=<?php echo $_GET['newsid'];?> 

<input name="update" type="submit" value="update" />
```

Most likely there is something that I don´t see  but "seeing" has taken almost 2 days now
... Is there a possibility I don´t have "edit" privileges in the mySql?

Comment: I don't think the last comma in your update query should be there.

Comment: Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know there was no error? Your code lacks:

```
 print mysql_error();
```

Add it right after the UPDATE query.

Also your code is most likely to fail whenever the submitted content itself contains single quotes. To send correct SQL to the database it's advisable to apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` on *all* input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result= mysql_query('UPDATE news SET 
date = "'. $date .'", 
time = "'. $time. '", 
location = "' .$location. '" 
WHERE newsid = '.$newsid.';') OR die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Comment: it throws a syntax error thou php-verifyer says the code is right... trying to debug it but your code seems to be close

Comment: Are the fields date and time VARCHAR's or what type do you have specified?

Comment: And I supposed 'newsid' is an Integer. If not, change the last line to "WHERE newsid = "' .$newsid. '";') ......